Is it possible to drill a mounting hole to reverse a refrigerator door?
I have a Frigidaire FRT18S6JS4 that came with stainless steel doors.  The doors did not come with any mounting holes on the doors to reverse them.  The body of the refrigerator does have the tapped holes for reversing the doors if they were set up to.
Is it possible to drill a mounting hole in the doors in order to reverse them?



Do you have a picture of the top of the door? The parts diagram shows the door as reversible so I wonder what is going on with yours.

See if the holes are covered by plugs. However, drilling could ruin the door: many modern refrigerators have high-vacuum panels (similar to a Thermos bottle or Dewar flask) to improve efficiency. Even a pinhole in such a panel destroys its insulating ability.

@DrMoishePippik IME refrigerator doors are simply an exterior metal skin with a molded plastic interior skin, and foam insulation sandwiched in between.

@brink Can you show us pics of your doors where holes should be?

@KMJ I've added an image to the original post.  There is no precut hole to reverse the doors.

Probably no.
While the parts diagram seems to show plugs, online listings for that fridge specify the door swing and say that it’s not reversible.
The underlying issue is that hinge assemblies have to be substantial. Just screwing a plate into thin steel, or worse, putting a hinge pin into foam isn’t likely to work well over the long term.
A very unlikely scenario would be finding doors of the opposite swing and using those.

The manufacturer states the door of the stainless steel model is not reversible. It is likely that they made design choices that preclude reversing the door. There is probably no reinforcement plate to hang the door on the other side of the unit. Unless you get info from the mfgr on this it is very likely that trying this would ruin the refrigerator.

@JimStewart  I've added an image of the door.  There is a plate for the chassis but no hole in the door for the hinges.

The pull handles on the door have to be reversible too. Contact the mfgr before drilling the door...


Stainless steel doors are not reversible.

See page 7 of the Owner's Manual.
That said, if you have a bit of fabrication skill you could probably disassemble the door, have a look at what underlying structure supports the current hinge location, and recreate that in some way. You'd want to reuse the nylon cup for durability and quiet operation.

I should have looked for that. Because when all else fails, RTFM.
